# Corebluetooth connection how to save battery level while it is connected

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, bluetooth, battery

Am going to use core bluetooth framework to my application.But i would like to know when i am connecting with another BLE device with long period of time in this situation how do i handle battery level, because it will reduce too fast while connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the example how you can get battery level

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[device setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
float level = [device batteryLevel];
```

Comment: I Know how to get battery level in iphone, but i would like to know if i am connecting two BLE support devices with entire day and it should not battery get drained soon.

Comment: you can handle UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification notification just add the code to your viewDidLoad [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryLevelChanged:) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];

Comment: Hai taffarel thanks for your reply, its very usefull to find battery level i think,i will check with this